# Por que isNaN(null) retorna "false"?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, números, ecmascript

Deparei-me com uma situação onde `undefined` e `null` retornam um valor diferente para a função `isNaN`, enquanto eu esperava que ambos retornariam `true` (não são números).

No exemplo abaixo coloquei também uma string `abc` e um número `123` para a função `isNaN`, que me retornam o valor esperado.

```js
console.log('isNaN(undefined):', isNaN(undefined)); // true
console.log('isNaN(null):', isNaN(null)); // false
console.log('isNaN("abc"):', isNaN("abc")); // true
console.log('isNaN(123):', isNaN(123)); // false
```

- Por que `null` está sendo considerado um número e `undefined` não?
- Esse é o comportamento esperado ou pode variar de acordo com o ambiente (navegador, Node.js, Deno etc.)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Por que `isNaN(null)` retorna `false`?

Porque `null` pode ser convertido a uma representação numérica em JavaScript. No caso, `null` é "equivalente" ao número `0` após a coerção.

A diferença pode ser notada a partir deste exemplo:

```js
console.log(Number(null), isNaN(null)); // 0 false
console.log(Number(undefined), isNaN(undefined)); // NaN true
```

O JavaScript é uma linguagem que eventualmente faz coerções de tipo automáticas. O construtor `Number` nos permite fazer essa coerção ao tipo `number` explicitamente. Verificando esse comportamento, nota-se que `null` é *convertível* ao tipo numérico (resultando em `0`), enquanto `undefined` não (resultando em `NaN`).

A função (presente no escopo global) `isNaN` verifica se o argumento pode ser corretamente convertido a uma representação numérica. Caso a conversão for possível, retorna-se `true` e, caso contrário, não. É por isso que `isNaN(null)` retorna `false` e `isNaN(undefined)` retorna `true`.

---

Vale lembrar que [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) (do escopo global) é *diferente* do método estático [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). A nomenclatura é confusa e, seguindo o nome, ambos tinham que fazer a mesma coisa, mas:

- `isNaN` verifica se o argumento pode ser convertido corretamente a uma representação numérica (sem retornar `NaN`). Verifique o [algoritmo](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-isnan-number) especificado para o `isNaN`.
- `Number.isNaN` verifica (utilizando um algoritmo diferente, porém similar, ao do `===`) se o argumento passado é igual a `NaN`. Consulte a [especificação](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-number.isnan) dele também.

O `isNaN` global trabalha com um conjunto maior de valores. Antagonicamente, o `Number.isNaN` retornará `true` apenas quando o valor passado ser, literalmente, igual a `NaN`. Caso contrário, sempre retornará `false`.

Alguns exemplos para se constatar a diferença:

```js
console.log(isNaN(5), Number.isNaN(5)); // false false
console.log(isNaN(NaN), Number.isNaN(NaN)); // true true
console.log(isNaN(null), Number.isNaN(null)); // false false
console.log(isNaN(undefined), Number.isNaN(undefined)); // true false
```

> Esse é o comportamento esperado ou pode variar de acordo com o ambiente (navegador, Node.js, Deno etc.)?

O comportamento de ambas as funções é estandardizado pela especificação. Portanto, é de se esperar que funcione em todos os *browsers* e *runtimes*.

A única ressalva é que `Number.isNaN` foi introduzido no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6).

Answer (score 5):

A pergunta já foi respondida, mas gostaria de acrescentar aqui algumas informações.

### O comportamento de `isNaN`

O comportamento mencionado na pergunta está conforme as especificações do ECMAScript, visto que [`isNaN`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-isnan-number) realiza a verificação através das especificações de [`ToNumber`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) - se `ToNumber` retorna `NaN` ou não:

> Returns true if the argument coerces to NaN, and otherwise returns false.
>
> 1. If ToNumber(number) is NaN, return true.
> 2. Otherwise, return false.

Sabendo que `isNaN` de fato busca a representação numérica do valor dado, apenas nos resta saber, por definição do ECMAScript, o que `ToNumber(null)` e `ToNumber(undefined)` deveriam retornar.

### A conversão para número (`ToNumber`)

`ToNumber` é uma operação abstrata que [segue o seguinte algoritmo](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) (em tradução livre):

| Tipo do Argumento | Resultado |
| --- | --- |
| Undefined | Retorna `NaN`. |
| Null | Retorna `+0`. |
| Boolean | Se o argumento for `true`, retorna `1`. Se o argumento for `false`, retorna `+0`. |
| Number | Retorna o argumento (sem conversão). |
| String | [Veja o algoritmo aqui](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type). |
| Symbol | Lança uma exceção `TypeError`. |
| BigInt | Lança uma exceção `TypeError`. |
| Object | Aplica os seguintes passos: 1. Converter para primitivo com [`ToPrimitive`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive). 2. Retornar `ToNumber(valorPrimitivo)`. |

Então isso já nos responde que `isNaN(undefined) === true` e `isNaN(null) === false` são o comportamento esperado. E como esse comportamento está nas especificações do ECMAScript, não varia de acordo com o ambiente.

---

E, como é de se imaginar, o algoritmo do `ToNumber` pode ser observado em ação através da chamada à função [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#description) - isso porque [quando o `Number` é chamado como função, ele realiza uma conversão de tipos](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-number-constructor-number-value):

```js
console.log('undefined:', Number(undefined)); // NaN
console.log('null:', Number(null)); // 0
```

Comment: Agora resta saber quem foi que decidiu que `undefined` é NaN e `null` é zero...

Comment: @hkotsubo eu estava colocando uma referência das definições de `undefined` e `null` na resposta, mas nenhuma delas facilitava essa interpretação de que um é `NaN` e o outro é `0`, então resolvi retirar hahaha. Mas por curiositade, estão aqui: [undefined](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-undefined-value) `primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value` e [null](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-null-value) `primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value`

Comment: É, pela definição, *talvez* faça sentido. Se não tem nenhum valor, não tem como converter para número. E se é "ausência de valor intencional", o zero seria o valor "similar", pois é o número que serve para indicar que não tem nada...

Answer (score 3):

O `typeof` de `null` é `object`, podendo se comportar de várias formas diferentes, causando esse tipo de comportamento. Isso acontece devido às funções `prototype` de um objeto, por exemplo, implementando `toString` um objeto pode se comportar como `string` em determinados casos.

Para entender melhor esse caso, entenda que o `isNaN` receberá tudo como `Number(valor)`. Nesse caso, `Number(null)` retornará `0`. Por isso `isNaN` retorna `false`.

Leia `isNaN(valor)` como `isNaN(Number(valor))`.

Mas isso é curioso, apesar de `Number(null)` retornar `0`, `null` é diferente de `0` mesmo com a comparação `==`:

```js
console.log(null == 0); // false
```

---

Por isso eu gosto de TypeScript rs. Talvez com **tipagem** você não chegue perto desse tipo de problema.