# Posso usar isNaN() para verificar se uma string contém somente dígitos de 0 a 9?

Tags: javascript, string

Estou lendo o livro "Programação JavaScript da série Use a Cabeça!" e não estou conseguindo localizar um erro que o livro pede para identificarmos, segue o desafio:

> Pegue um número de telefone na forma "123-4567" e escreva um código para aceitá-lo ou rejeitá-lo. Para ser aceito o número deve ter sete dígitos, 0 até 9, com um traço no meio.
>
> ```
> function validate(phoneNumber) {
>     if (phoneNumber.length !== 8) {
>         return false;
>     } 
>
>     var first = phoneNumber.substring(0,3);
>     var second = phoneNumber.substring(4);
>     
>     if (phoneNumber.charAt(3) !== "-" || isNaN(first) || isNaN(second)) {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return true;
> };
> ```
>
> Você consegue imaginar algum bug que o programador tenha introduzido com o seu uso de `isNaN()`?

Fiz diversos testes aqui, mas o código parece funcionar corretamente quando insiro um número no formato especificado, não consegui encontrar o bug.

Comment: Relacionada ou dup: [Por que isNaN(null) retorna "false"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484999/por-que-isnannull-retorna-false?rq=1)

Comment: `isNaN('1e2')`, por exemplo, retornará `false`, mesmo não sendo um número válido para telefone. O `e` é utilizado para notações científicas, mas não lembro bem o suficiente para poder explicar isso melhor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que a função retorna `true` para vários casos em que deveria retornar `false` (ou seja, dá falsos positivos: diz que um telefone inválido é válido). Exemplos:

```js
function validate(phoneNumber) {
    if (phoneNumber.length !== 8) {
        return false;
    }
    var first = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3);
    var second = phoneNumber.substring(4);
    if (phoneNumber.charAt(3) !== "-" || isNaN(first) || isNaN(second)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

for (var tel of ['-12-3e10', '   -    ', '0.2-   3', '+00--0.3'])
    console.log(`${tel}=${validate(tel)}`);
```

Repare que todas as strings acima (`'-12-3e10'`, `'   -    '`, `'0.2-   3'` e `'+00--0.3'`) são consideradas telefones válidos, e a saída do código é:

```
-12-3e10=true
   -    =true
0.2-   3=true
+00--0.3=true
```

Isso acontece porque segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-isnan-number), `isNaN` usa [este algoritmo](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tonumber) para converter seu argumento para número.
No caso específico de strings, é usada a [operação `StringToNumber`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-stringtonumber), que por sua vez usa [este algoritmo](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-stringnumericvalue) para obter o valor numérico que a string representa. E este algoritmo não funciona somente com dígitos de 0 a 9, pois há várias outras strings que podem ser convertidas para número.

Claro que strings como `'123'` são corretamente identificadas como válidas. Mas o mesmo acontece com `'-12'` (que representa o número negativo `-12`), ou `'3e10'` (número em notação científica, que representa 3 x 10<sup>10</sup>, ou seja, `30000000000` - 30 bilhões), ou ainda `'0.2'` (número com casas decimais), `'+00'`  (zero), `'-0.3'` (número negativo e com casas decimais), etc.

Talvez o caso com espaços seja o mais estranho, mas é porque uma string que só contém espaços é convertida para o número zero, e portanto `isNaN` retorna `false` para este caso, conforme citado na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#examples). E no caso do    `3`, também é considerado um número válido porque os espaços do início e fim da string são ignorados.

Ou seja, usar `isNaN` para verificar se uma string só contém caracteres que correspondem aos dígitos de 0 a 9 está errado, porque esta função considera vários outros casos que possuem caracteres diferentes. Sendo assim, ela não é adequada para este problema, pois apesar de funcionar com telefones válidos, ela não funciona para vários casos inválidos (dizendo erroneamente que são válidos).

---

Portanto, uma forma de resolver é verificar explicitamente se os caracteres são dígitos de 0 a 9:

```js
function validate(phoneNumber) {
    if (phoneNumber.length !== 8) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length; i++) {
        if (i === 3) { // posição que deve ter hífen
            if (phoneNumber[i] !== '-') {
                return false;
            }
        } else { // posição deve ter dígito de 0 a 9
            if (phoneNumber[i] < '0' || phoneNumber[i] > '9') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

for (var tel of ['-12-3e10', '   -    ', '0.2-   3', '+00--0.3', '123-4567', '000-9999'])
    console.log(`${tel}=${validate(tel)}`);
```

Ou seja, para a posição que deve ter o hífen, eu verifico se tem esse caractere. Para todas as outras posições, verifico se o caractere corresponde a um dígito de 0 a 9.

Agora ela retorna `false` para os quatro primeiros (que de fato são inválidos), e `true` para os dois seguintes (que são válidos).

---

E claro, provavelmente alguém vai sugerir pra usar regex:

```js
function validate(phoneNumber) {
    return /^\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(phoneNumber);
}

for (var tel of ['-12-3e10', '   -    ', '0.2-   3', '+00--0.3', '123-4567', '000-9999'])
    console.log(`${tel}=${validate(tel)}`);
```

No caso, os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` indicam o início e fim da string, assim garanto que ela só vai ter o que está na regex (nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos). Depois o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` pega um dígito de 0 a 9, e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{n}` indica a quantidade (ou seja, primeiro tem 3 dígitos, e depois do hífen tem 4).

Apesar de ser mais curto, regex em geral [é mais lento](https://jsbench.me/v7kvckvfhv/1) (e muitas vezes mais difícil de entender e manter).

Comment: No fundo, a lição que fica é: não teste apenas com os casos válidos, tem que testar com os inválidos também :-)

Comment: dica de ouro dos testes :D

Comment: Da pra evitar vários dos problemas do isNaN utilizando Number.isNaN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN